# React native error undefined is not a function auth and provider

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am writing a React Native application and using the firebase library. I'm making a sign up button for a google account. But a mistake. What should I do, maybe I imported incorrectly?

````
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  const handleCreaceAccount = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('CREATE !!!!!!!');
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch(erorr => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(app);
  function singUp() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(result => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        //const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        //const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        // ...
        alert(user.displayName);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.customData.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
  }```[enter image description here][1] [enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwp9i.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvpgB.png
````

Comment: Pls show your imports.